# How can a C# parameter with default value be null?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

The code shown below shows a method `Get` which gets string `search` with default value: `""`.

[image: Image showing null value for a parameter that has a default value]

How can the value possibly be null when `search` has a non-null default value and is never changed?

Comment: If the parameter is present (but null) the default value won't be used.

Comment: How are you calling the Get for MainView?

Comment: Since this is Web API, you may want to check the raw request to see what values are being passed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can the value possibly be null when search has a non-null default value and is never changed?

If you explicitly pass `null` to the method (or a variable which is null), the default is not used.

The default value is only used if you call the method *without* the parameter in place, in which case the compiler "fills in" the default value for you.  If you call the method with something, including `null` or a object variable which is `null`, you will get a null value there.

Comment: It *might* be worth mentioning that if the method is FooCorp.DLL and BarCorp.DLL is the caller, and FooCorp alters the method's default, calls from BarCorp.DLL will keep using the old value unless that assembly is also recompiled.

Comment: Very true - as I said, the compiler "fills in" the default *at compile time*, which is a downside to default arguments in general.